# T-SQL (date) - how to get value within one hour?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am looking for an optimal decision of how to get table values according to their date and time but within just ONE past hour.

I mean something in this way (a pseudocode):

```
 SELECT value FROM Table WHERE date BETWEEN getdate() AND getdate()-ONE_HOUR
```

For the purpose of this question `Table` has these columns:

- `value`
- `date`

Any useful snippet is appreciated :)

Comment: As a rule, it is best to invoke GetDate() once and save the value in a variable, then use the variable as needed.  It avoids all sorts of nasties around midnight.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT Value
FROM Table
WHERE Date between dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Description of the `DATEADD` function:

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

```
datepart     Abbreviations  
-----------  -------------
year         yy, yyyy
quarter      qq, q
month        mm, m
dayofyear    dy, y
day          dd, d
week         wk, ww
weekday      dw, w
hour         hh 
minute       mi, n
second       ss, s
millisecond  ms 
microsecond  mcs 
nanosecond   ns
```

More information:

- [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: It is interesting. Thanks. And what if I use const like -3 in this function? Will it give me past 3 hours value result then?

Comment: Affirmative.  The number value (param 2) is added to (or with a negative value, subtracted) the date value (param 3).  If you used day instead of hour, it'd subtract 1 (in my example) days instead of 1 hours, and a -3 would make it subtract 3 days.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT value
FROM Table 
WHERE date >= dateadd(hour,-1,getdate())
   and date <= getdate()
```

Comment: Comment retraced.  I'm not sure whether >= and <= or between is more efficient though... one day I'll have to test.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - No difference what so ever. The predicate will appear as `>=` and `<=` in the plan anyway.